# How to correctly compute p-value for hypothesis test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

Let the random variable X represent the amount of money carried by a student in class. To determine μ , the mean amount of money carried by a student, an experiment was conducted in class. The class was divided into four groups, and random samples from each group was taken. From Groups 1 and 2, random samples of size n=5 were taken, while from Groups 3 and 4, random samples of size n=10 were taken. Some sample results for the four groups are shown below.

```
Group Average
1     46.60
2     6.80
3     16.00
4     13.90
```

Your instructor is interested in testing the following hypothesis about the mean amount of money carried by a student: 
H0: μ ≥ 28.79 
H1: μ < 28.79

Assume that the amount of money carried by a student follows a Normal distribution, and s2 = 4929.1. **Using the average results for Group 2 from the above table, what is the p-value for this test?**

**I'm getting the answer as .24, while the correct answer is .2611.** What did I do wrong?

**I first calculated z-score as (6.80-28.79)/sqrt(4929.1/5) = -0.7.**

**P(z<-0.7) = 0.24**

Comment: It's a $t$ test, not a z-test.

Comment: @Glen_b, so "Assume that the amount of money carried by a student follows a Normal distribution, and s2 = 4929.1." <-- is this talking about standard deviation of sample then? I thought it was standard deviation of the population. Can you please confirm? Thanks!

Comment: $s^2$ normally denotes a sample variance; $\sigma^2$ would be the population variance. I don't have what you can see (I only have what's above to go by), nor do I have any contact with the source you got the question from, so I can only assume they're following typical convention (and that you're reproducing what was actually asked). You will note (from my answer below) that assuming that $s^2$ is a sample variance results in the p-value you quoted but couldn't reproduce; that's a big clue that I have correctly guessed what is intended. I am not going to get a p-value right to 4dp by accident.

Comment: Oh, I am/was 100% sure you were right. What I wanted was some help so that I don't repeat this mistake again (confusing sample standard deviation for population standard deviation), and you did help me by pointing out that it's because of s^2, so big thanks for that.

Comment: In real problems, rather than textbook problems, you normally won't have any population quantities, except in special circumstances\*. (If you have the population variance, why don't you know the population mean?) So one thing to keep in mind for real-world problems is that in almost all cases variances will be sample variances. $ $ \* An example of an exception is when the variance is a function of the population mean, such as when testing proportions; under $H_0$ the population mean is specified, so the distribution of the sample mean under $H_0$ can be done with known variance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on my comment:

If you know the population standard deviation, you can do a z-test, because $\frac{\bar x - \mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt n}$ will have a standard normal distribution when $H_0$ is true.

However, normally you *don't* know the population standard deviation, so you must estimate it from the sample, giving you $\frac{\bar x - \mu_0}{s/\sqrt n}$. Because the sample standard deviation can be larger or smaller than $\sigma$, the distribution of the test statistic is both more sharply peaked and heavier tailed than normal - specifically, it has a Student's $t$ distribution. There are many t-distributions, described by the degrees of freedom.

The more observations you use to estimate the standard deviation, the more accurately (in a particular sense) it tends to estimate $\sigma$. The degrees of freedom of the t-distribution correspond to the degrees of freedom used in calculating $s$, the estimate of $\sigma$.

Because in your one sample test, you estimated one mean parameter, you lose one degree of freedom, leaving you with $n-1=4$ degrees of freedom in your estimate of $\sigma$, and hence your $t$ distribution under the null hypothesis has 4 degrees of freedom

[image]

So you have to find the one-tailed p-value for a $t_4$ statistic of $-0.70037$. In R that comes out like so:

```
 pt(-0.70037,df=4)
[1] 0.2611462
```

Some further reading on Wikipedia:

[One sample t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#One-sample_t-test)

[t-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution)